# Enable Quick Look for text files without the .txt extension

Tags: macos, text, quicklook

Doing *Quick Look* on `.txt` files is very convenient (select in *Finder* and press space).

Is there a way to enable Quick Look for other text files which don't have the `.txt` extension (e.g., `.strings` files)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

People can develop plugins to allow Quick Look to support more file types. You can find [Apple's Quick Look documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Luckily though Timac (aka Alexandre Colucci) has already created one. You can find [Timac's Quick Look plugin for strings files here](http://blog.timac.org/?p=933).

Just download the compiled plugin, copy it to your `/Library/QuickLook` folder and run the `qlmanage -r` command in the Terminal to refresh the Quick Look plugin cache and you should now be able to view previews of files with ".strings" extensions. He even made his plugin capable enough to read .strings files that aren't plain text; some .strings files are in a binary format.

He also supplies the source on his blog, at the same link above, which should help point you in the right direction if you wanted to create a plugin for other similar files that you want Quick Look to recognise.

Comment: It would be cool if there was a fork that attempted to display the contents of any file that isn't photo or video in the preview window.

Answer (score 31):

[QLStephen](http://whomwah.github.io/qlstephen/) is a more general solution that works for all kinds of text files.

Comment: This is the best! Works for all text files.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the pointed plugin satisfies the asked question better ("without .txt extension").

Comment: It helped, but with files like `config` it still does not show the content.  I have 1.4.3.

Comment: This hasn't worked for years...

Comment: @PatrickT Working for me on Monterey (but I needed to allow the developer in Gatekeeper)

Comment: @PatrickT just got it to work on Catalina.  On the website follow the link to GitHub with a more recent version and directions on how allow it in GateKeeper.